# file deletion operation getting failed on the SD card

Tags: android

Android file deletion operation getting failed on the SD card .

following is my code .

```
File testingfile = new File("file path in SD card");
try{

boolean bool = testingfile.delete();
}
catch(){
Log.d (TAG, e.printmessage());
}
```

Permissions (already granted ):-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

the file is not getting deleted . the bool always return false.

My  buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"